# r: lapply value assignment

Tags: r, variable-assignment, lapply

I want to replace the second letter of every string in the following vector with x.

```
ba <- c('ba','aba','baba')
# goal: bx, axa, bxba
```

Normally I would just use `substr(ba,2,2) <- 'x'`. But for reasons too complicated to go into here, I'm trying to avoid `substr` and instead looking for another solution. So I tried splitting the strings up and replacing the second element of each list. But I'm getting this error message.

```
ba2 <- strsplit(ba,'')
lapply(ba2,function(x) x[2]) <- 'x'
# Error in lapply(ba2, function(x) x[2]) <- "x" : 
# could not find function "lapply<-"
```

How can I work around this problem? Is there a way to use `lapply` in conjunction with `<-`?

Comment: `sub` is better. for the `lapply` / `strsplit`, method, you'd do `sapply(lapply(strsplit(ba, ""), function(x) {x[2] <- "x"; x}), paste, collapse="")` or `sapply(strsplit(ba, ""), function(x) {x[2] <- "x"; paste(x, collapse="")})`.

Comment: Another alternative with `substr` rather than `substr<-` is `paste0(substr(ba, 1, 1), "x", substr(ba, 3, 100))`.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! I had no idea you could embed two commands separated by `;` inside `sapply`. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

Use regexp substitution:

```
sub("^(.).", "\\1x", ba)
```

Explanation:

- ^ - beginning of word
- (.) - take an arbitrary character, and memorize it
- . another arbitrary character
- \1 - replace by the memorized character
- ... and 'x'